# How does Swap slot works in azure portal

Tags: azure, xamarin, hockeyapp

We have two web APIs hosted on azure for staging and production.
And we are consuming those APIs in mobile app where we provided which API should be used.

Right Now we are testing with staging app with staging mobile app.

If we do production app deployment and do swap slot from staging to production, does it will affect the staging app.

We have 2 different versions on hockeyapp staging and production mobile app.  After swap slot does staging app will still point to staging API?

Should we standard API publish method.

Any help on this appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slot swap switches the apps to the other slot.

So the app version in production will be running in staging and the one which was running in staging is now in production.

In my opinion you are using them a bit wrong here.
The purpose of deployment slots is to allow a "staged deployment" where new code can be published to the slot without bothering production, and then hot-swapped with minimal downtime.

What you really need is a testing environment, which you target from your testing app.

When deploying you deploy to staging and then swap to production.